# Laravel 5.1 get Orders that have been completed

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.1, pivot-table

I have an `Order` model and an `OrderStatus` model. An `Order` can have multiple statuses but only one 'currentStatus' (this is defined by the `created_at` timestamp on the pivot table `order_status`).

`Order` model (`orders` table)

`OrderStatus` model (`order_statuses` table)

`order_status` pivot table (`order_status` table)

How can I define a query scope (or similar) to get all the `Orders` of a certain status; i.e. 'completed'?

The following doesn't work as it checks all statuses of the orders, even ones in the past.

```
public function scopeCompleted($query)
{
    return $query->whereHas('statuses', function($q) {
        return $q->where('statuses.id', 10);
    });
}
```

The generated SQL is:

```
select  *
    from  `orders`
    where  `orders`.`deleted_at` is null
      and (
        SELECT  count(*)
            from  `statuses`
            inner join  `order_status`  ON `statuses`.`id` = `order_status`.`status_id`
            where  `status`.`id` = `orders`.`id`
              and  `statuses`.`id` = ?
          ) >= 1
```

This incorrectly returns all orders that *have* had a status with the ID of 10, rather than only returning orders that **currently** have the status with an ID of 10.

**order_status** pivot table

```
+----+----------+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+
| id | order_id | order_status_id | approver_id | approved_at         |
+----+----------+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+
| 11 | 2        | 9               | NULL        | 2017-04-10 13:33:25 |
+----+----------+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+
| 10 | 2        | 10              | NULL        | 2017-04-10 13:33:25 |
+----+----------+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+
| 9  | 2        | 5               | NULL        | 2017-04-10 13:33:25 |
+----+----------+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+
| 8  | 2        | 2               | NULL        | 2017-04-10 13:33:25 |
+----+----------+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+
| 7  | 2        | 1               | NULL        | 2017-04-10 13:33:25 |
+----+----------+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+
| 6  | 1        | 10              | NULL        | 2017-04-10 13:32:09 |
+----+----------+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+
| 5  | 1        | 9               | NULL        | 2017-04-10 13:32:05 |
+----+----------+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+
| 4  | 1        | 7               | NULL        | 2017-04-10 13:32:05 |
+----+----------+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+
| 3  | 1        | 5               | NULL        | 2017-04-10 13:32:05 |
+----+----------+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+
| 2  | 1        | 2               | NULL        | 2017-04-10 13:32:05 |
+----+----------+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+
| 1  | 1        | 1               | NULL        | 2017-04-10 13:32:05 |
+----+----------+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+
```

For example, the above `order_status` pivot table shows two orders with multiple status entries. From this, when asking for the completed orders (status 10) only one order (the order with an ID of 1) should be returned as order 2 is no longer completed, it has since been updated with another status.

Comment: Please show us the generated SQL.

Comment: @RickJames I have updated my question to include the SQL too. Thanks

Comment: This would be much easier if you keep a `current_status_id` field in your orders table and you update it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

First, this would be better:

```
select  *
    from  `orders`
    where  `orders`.`deleted_at` is null
      and EXISTS (
        SELECT  *
            from  `statuses`
            inner join  `order_status`
                ON `statuses`.`id` = `order_status`.`status_id`
            where  `status`.`id` = `orders`.`id`
              and  `statuses`.`id` = ?
                 );
```

You don't really need the full count, you just need to know if any exist.

But the query is impossible since there is no `status` table mentioned!

Once you have fixed that, we can discuss how to avoid a subquery.

Comment: The OrderStatus table stores all the possible statuses, and the order_status pivot table keeps the relationships between the two. I managed to solve it earlier with subqueries and it is working, however you imply using sub-queries is bad, no? If so, how would I go about it in a different way?

Comment: Subqueries are often slow.  Perhaps your tables are not big enough yet to see the sluggishness.

Comment: How would you suggest getting the completed orders then if not using sub queries?

Comment: You need [_groupwise max_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max) to get only the 'current' rows.